# c++11 and boost_filesystem cout and printf doesn't work

Tags: c++, boost, c++11, printf, cout

I've run into a problem with printf and cout when using boost/filesystem.hpp

I created a c++ project in eclipse juno with mingw settings

objectfile.hpp contains declarations and #include "boost/filesystem.hpp"
objectfile.cpp contains definitions and usage of boost:: filesystem:: exists(...)
mainfile.cpp contains the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  printf("asdf\n");
  cout <<"asdf"<<endl;
  return 0;
}
```

mainfile.cpp doesn't include the header of objectfile.hpp but gets linked in the linking stage. Also boost_system and boost_filesystem are linked.

Problem: output is empty. There is no output whatsoever until I remove boost/filesystem.hpp and the corresponding code and then recompile.

I haven't tested with other boost libraries yet. Maybe someone else has had a similar problem?

Windows 7 64 bit
Eclipse Juno 64 bit -std=c++11 compiler option
Boost 1.51 multi threaded dynamically linked

### UPDATE

I rebuilt Boost 1.51 with these options:
    -j8 toolset=gcc cxxflags=-std=gnu++0x variant=release optimization=speed link=static threading=multi --layout=system --prefix=boost install

**and now it works.**

thank you **Marshall Clow**. Submit an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: Can you verify different exit codes (if you vary them)? Can you do so with the two cout/printf lines commented out?

Comment: In C++ you should use #include <cstdio> rather than #include<stdio.h>, though i doubt it'll fix your problem

Comment: Did you build your boost libraries with the same compiler options? (`std=c++11`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resubmitting as an answer:

Is it possible that you built the boost libraries with different compiler options than your program? Specifically, I would check `std=c++11`.